# Compare and Process Common and Uncommon files separately

Tags: array, bash, shell

I have the following files:

- STUDENT_**D19001**.T103412_HU.txt
- STUDENT_**D19001**.T103412_KU.txt
- STUDENT_**D19002**.T113030_HU.txt
- STUDENT_**D19002**.T115055_KU.txt
- STUDENT_**D19003**.T115055_KU.txt
- STUDENT_**D19004**.T135040_HU.txt

I want to process the **common/pair files** separately in this order (HU1 and then KU1; HU2 and then KU2) and the **uncommon/unpaired files** separately.

These two files (`STUDENT_D19001.T103412_HU.txt` and `STUDENT_D19001.T103412_KU.txt`) are common/pair files because they have same day of the year `001` in their name. However, these two files (`STUDENT_D19003.T115055_KU.txt` and `STUDENT_D19004.T135040_HU.txt`) are uncommon/unpaired because the do not have the same day of year with other files.

The output of the script is illustrated below for further clarification:

```
*** Uncommon/Unpaired files: ***
Processing './STUDENT_D19003.T115055_KU.txt'
Processing './STUDENT_D19004.T135040_HU.txt'

*** Common/Pair files: ***
1 of : 4 './STUDENT_D19001.T103412_HU.txt'
2 of : 4 './STUDENT_D19001.T103412_KU.txt'
3 of : 4 './STUDENT_D19002.T113030_HU.txt'
4 of : 4 './STUDENT_D19002.T115055_KU.txt'
```

Here is the script for review:

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE_DIR="."

#
# Create an array of all the HU files
#
HU_files=()
while IFS='' read -r -d '' file
do
    HU_files+=("$file")
done < <(find "$SOURCE_DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*HU*" -printf '%p\0' | sort -zn)

#
# Calculate HU total files
#
total_HU="${#HU_files[@]}"

#
# Create an array of all the BFV files
#
KU_files=()
while IFS='' read -r -d '' file
do
    KU_files+=("$file")
done < <(find "$SOURCE_DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*KU*" -printf '%p\0' | sort -zn)

#
# Calculate KU total files
#
total_KU="${#KU_files[@]}"


# Find common/pair HU and KU files considering partial part name 'STUDENT_D19001'
COMMON_files=()
i=0
k=0

while [ $i -lt $total_HU ] 
do
    j=0 
    while [ $j -lt $total_KU ] 
    do
        if [[ "${HU_files[$i]/.T*/}" == "${KU_files[$j]/.T*/}" ]]
        then
            COMMON_files[$((k++))]="${HU_files[$i]}"
            COMMON_files[$((k++))]="${KU_files[$j]}"
            break
        else 
            ((j++))
        fi
    done
    ((i++))
done

# Process uncommon/unpaired HU and KU files
echo "*** Uncommon/Unpair files: ***"
while IFS='' read -r -d '' file
do
    if [[ ! "${COMMON_files[@]}" =~ "${file}" ]]
    then
    echo "Processing '$file'"
    fi
done < <(find "$SOURCE_DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -iname "*HU*.txt" -o -iname "*KU*.txt" \) -printf '%p\0' | sort -zn)

#
# Process the common/pair HU and KU files
#
total_COMMOM="${#COMMON_files[@]}"
counter=0
echo "*** Common/Pair files: ***"
for file in "${COMMON_files[@]}"
do  
    echo "$((++counter)) of $total_COMMOM: '$file'"
done
```

Your inputs are appreciated :-)

Comment: Imagine that there would be 2 **HU** files (not `HU` and `KU`) with same `D19001`, like `STUDENT_D19001.T103412_HU.txt` and `STUDENT_D19001.T103515_HU.txt`. How would that effect the expected result and how it should look in such case?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Such a case will not occur because there are two files HU and KU with day of the year part of their name. However, sometimes it happens that there is only either HU or KU which are considered unpaired.

Comment: Is some real processing implied for "uncommon" files or it's just for printing?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest of course there is. Here the print is only for debugging purpose.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest they could be moved to another directory for further investigation for example ...

Answer (score 1):

Per shell checkers feedback, I suggest the following changes:

**Fix#1**
To prevent globing and word splitting it is recommended to use double quote. Hence, update this `while [ $i -lt $total_HU ]` to `while [ $i -lt "$total_HU" ]`, and this `while [ $j -lt $total_KU ]` to `while [ $j -lt "$total_KU" ]`. I am aware we are dealing with number rather than string but no harm to double quote variables.

**Fix#2** 
Per [SC2199](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2199) and [SC2076](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2076) this line of code `if [[ ! "${COMMON_files[@]}" =~ "${file}" ]]` is problematic, therefore, I changed it to `if [[ ! "${COMMON_files[*]}" =~ ${file} ]]`.

In this context I am sure that I want to match literally so I could also use a trick like this `if [[ ! "${COMMON_files[*]}" =~ "${file}"* ]]`.